# SPSS Bootstrapping Medians - Two Groups Over Time

Tags: spss, bootstrap, median

I am evaluating the effects of two different teaching methods for chest compressions during CPR over time. I have four sets of data: a control and study group compressions per minute on the first day and again six weeks later. Because I have some outliers I am using medians in SPSS to evaluate the difference between the methods.

I did a 1000x bootstrap in SPSS and compared the medians of the two different teaching methods six weeks later and found a difference of 7, which I am happy to say is fairly insignificant. However, I would like to get the 95% CIs of the difference between the medians and am having trouble getting that information. I read through this post -> [How to construct a 95% confidence interval of the difference between medians?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27038/how-to-construct-a-95-confidence-interval-of-the-difference-between-medians) but am still a little lost.

Every time I rerun my bootstrap in SPSS I seem to come back with the same numbers. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can find these differences?